# Connection resets with simple Perl script

Tags: perl, tcp, reset

Below is a Perl script whose sole purpose is to receive an HTTP request, and spit out "503 Service Unavailable" and a short message. It works fine, except in many cases, the connection resets, which causes the browser to show an error message. This is on Win32. I have no idea what's wrong with it.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use strict;
use IO::Socket::INET;
my $f = join('', <DATA>);

$SIG{CHLD} = 'IGNORE';
my $sock = IO::Socket::INET->new(ReuseAddr => 1, Listen => 512, LocalPort => 80, LocalHost => '0.0.0.0', Proto => 'tcp');
die "Cant't create a listening socket: $@" unless $sock;

while (my $connection = $sock->accept) {
    my $child;
    die "Can't fork: $!" unless defined ($child = fork());
    if ($child == 0) {
        #print "Child $$ running. ";
        $sock->close;
        do_it($connection);
        #print "Child $$ exiting.\n";
        exit 0;
    } else {
        print "Connection from ".$connection->peerhost."\n";
        $connection->close();
    }
}

sub do_it {
    my $socket = shift;
    my $pr = print $socket $f;
    if (!$pr) {
        $socket->close();
        exit(0);
    }
}

__DATA__
HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
Date: Mon, 12 Mar 2009 19:12:16 GMT
Server: Down
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html


<html>
<head><title>Down for Maintenance</title></head>
<body>
<h2>Down for Maintenance</h2>
<p>The site is down for maintenance. It will be online again shortly.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Exactly which version of Windows are you trying this on? How many simultaneous connections?

Comment: It happens when it's just me on the local machine, and I hit refresh fast with my mouse (which is not that fast...). OS = XP.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't `fork` on Win32 known as *broken*?

Really since your child process is doing something totally different from your parent section, you might be better off with [threads](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlthrtut).

In answer to your question in the comments, just think about replacing all your forking logic (!!) with

```
$peer_name = $connection->peerhost();
threads->create( \&do_it, $connection );
say "Got connection from $peer_name";
```

( See [this](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlthrtut#Creating_Threads) for example. )
And don't worry about closing connection anywhere else but the server thread.

Comment: Is there an application that I can use that does what this script does? I won't be able to sort out this script to use threads in short time.

Comment: This sounds like it.  My guess is that the close() call in the parent is closing the child's descriptor too, and they are racing against each other.  Certainly doing Unix-style fork is never going to be a good choice on windows, even when it works.

Comment: @Andy Ross: I was thinking that, but I also wondered about the problem of having two separate processes both thinking they have the same descriptor open. That looks like pretty undefined behavior as well.

Answer (score 0):

Does [HTTP::Daemon](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTTP::Daemon) help? It is included in the core.

Results of searching Google for [windows xp sp3 tcp connection limit](http://www.google.com/search?q=windows+xp+sp3+tcp+connection+limit) might also be relevant.

Comment: I really don't think that article is referring to TCP, but rather SMB

Comment: @Hasturkun Thank you for pointing that I linked to the wrong article. I remember something about a limit on TCP connections as well, but I have not found the article yet.

Answer (score 0):

My module [HTTP::Server::Brick](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=http::server::brick&mode=all) works on Windows, but the tests hang on Strawberry perl unfortunately (it's on the todo list) so you would either need to do a manual install, or just copy in the single perl Module and use cpan to install the dependencies. It does however build/test fine under cygwin on Windows and of course on unix.

Here's how I'd implement your requirement using [HTTP::Server::Brick](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=http::server::brick&mode=all), noting that it is fairly naive and suffers from the same problem as yours in that there is no upper limit on the number of threads/processes.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use HTTP::Server::Brick;
use HTTP::Status qw(:constants);

my $server = HTTP::Server::Brick->new( port => 80 );

my $html = join '', <DATA>;

$server->mount( '/' => {
 wildcard => 1,
 handler => sub {
  my ($req, $res) = @_;
  $res->add_content($html);
  return HTTP_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE;
 },
   });

$server->start;

__DATA__
<html>
<head><title>Down for Maintenance</title></head>
<body>
<h2>Down for Maintenance</h2>
<p>The site is down for maintenance. It will be online again shortly.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Also a quick note about the comment re perl fork on windows known to be broken, it basically just uses perl threads to mimic the fork() call. It's not seamless, but for simple situations it's an easy way of using threads.

One final note - maybe you're just better off installing cygwin plus the apache or lighthttpd package? Sending a 503 for all urls is a pretty short apache config file.